# Silencing a -Wshift-count-overflow warning in a generic bitmask macro

Tags: c, gcc, clang, language-lawyer, bit-shift

I wrote this macro to get a bitmask generically:

```
#define BX_uint_least(Bits,Val) _Generic((char(*)[Bits]){0}, \
                                    char (*)[8]: (uint_least8_t)(Val), \
                                    char (*)[16]: (uint_least16_t)(Val), \
                                    char (*)[32]: (uint_least32_t)(Val), \
                                    char (*)[64]: (uint_least64_t)(Val))
#define BX_bitmask(Bits) ((BX_uint_least(Bits,1)<<Bits)-1)
```

but when I use it, it's generating `-Wshift-count-overflow` warnings.

Can these warnings be silenced from within the macro?

I don't want to silence them altogether because e.g., the UB-causing
`((int32_t)1)<<32` should still get a warning, but `((uint_least32_t)1)<<32` overflowing to 0 is completely harmless and intended.

Example program:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define BX_uint_least(Bits,Val) _Generic((char(*)[Bits]){0}, \
                                    char (*)[8]: (uint_least8_t)(Val), \
                                    char (*)[16]: (uint_least16_t)(Val), \
                                    char (*)[32]: (uint_least32_t)(Val), \
                                    char (*)[64]: (uint_least64_t)(Val))
#define BX_bitmask(Bits) ((BX_uint_least(Bits,1)<<Bits)-1)

int main() 
{

    //(void)((int32_t)1<<32); //UB; should warn
    (void)BX_bitmask(32); //shouldn't warn
    (void)(((uint32_t)1)<<32); //I don't care if it warns or not
}
```

By the way, the warning comes up with both gcc and clang without having to add any flags (such as `-Wall` or `-Wextra`), but by my reading of [6.5.7p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p4):

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
>   bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of
>   the result is E1 x 2E2 , reduced modulo one more than the maximum
>   value representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed type and
>   nonnegative value, and E1 x 2E2 is representable in the result type,
>   then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.

the result of e.g., `((uint32_t)1)<<32` is perfectly well-defined (to be `+(uint32_t)0`) so I think it's a little weird that a perfectly well defined operation should ellicit a warning in compiler invocation that doesn't requests extra warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit shifting by an amount equal to the bit size of the type is **undefined**.

Section 6.5.7p3 of the [C standard states](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands.  The
>   type of the result is that  of  the  promoted  left  operand.   **If 
>   the  value  of  the  right  operand  is  negative  or  is greater than
>   or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

So you can't perform `((uint_least32_t)1)<<32` or `((uint32_t)1)<<32` safely.

Comment: Oops must have missed that one. Thanks!